# add column dataset with correlation values in R

Tags: r, correlation

I have the following dataset and would like to add a new column with the correlation value for each rows of the  columns (temp and laten)

```
   edad talla dosis temp laten dur
1    37  1.62   370 37.5     7  35
2    24  1.58   350 37.5     6  30
3    19  1.62   375 37.5     8  25
4    23  1.64   380 37.5     6  40
5    35  1.58   350 22.0     8  20
6    31  1.57   325 37.5    10  30
7    28  1.68   380 22.0    10  15
8    29  1.60   350 37.5     8  20
9    22  1.66   380 37.5     7  20
10   36  1.70   380 22.0     9  25
```

How can I do it?thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this

```
for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
    df$corr[i] = cor(df$temp[1:i], df$laten[1:i])
}
```

Comment: nice guess, maybe this is it

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly!!

Answer (score -1):

cor(yourdataset) ? or maybe you would like to calculate cor by group ? by I don't se any factor var here

Comment: i want to calculate correlation between 2 variables but for each row, not for the complete column

Comment: its impossible what you are asking

Comment: The final purpose is to do the histogram associated to the correlation value, is not possible to plot an histogram having only one value.How can I do it?